# how to have two popunders on a single page that show separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The question is: I have a webpage and two popunders, i want them to show when someone click on specific elements on page, i mean `popunder1` shows when `element1` (like image1) is clicked and `popunder2` shows when `element2` (like `image2`) is clicked, how can i achieve that?

The code:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#image1').click(function(){
    //POPUNDER1 SCRIPT HERE 
    $(this).hide();
  });
});

$(function(){
  $('#image2').click(function(){
    //POPUNDER2 SCRIPT HERE 
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#image1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999999;
}
#image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100;
  z-index: 99999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <div id="image1">IMAGE1 HERE</div>
  <div id="image2">IMAGE2 HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your current code meant to do. Why the images (`#image`, `#image2`) are in `position: absolute`? You current jQuery just hide the element you click on it. Are you want that once the user clicks on an image, popunder (like tooltip) will show relative the element who clicked?

Comment: thanks for reply, yes i want each image shows its relative popunder when user clicks on it, the image position is not too important, i choose images as an example for a clickable area that are between div tags. as you know normally popunders show when someone clicks on page (it can be everywhere on page), i'm trying to trigger popunder when a user click on a specific area on page

Comment: By popunders do you mean something like modal? Something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)?

Comment: yes, kind of, but to be specific, here is a popunder generator website address: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/popunder.shtml

Comment: These are 2 different things. with dialog the user stays in the same window and with popunder the user moves to another **new** window. Which version do you want? If you want the second so just copy/paste his code.

Comment: it's working! thanks you very much man

Comment: I didn't do anything :) but.. my pleasure. Good luck..